# ¿Cómo quitar en el Response de symfony el status que me envia a la pantalla?

Tags: php, symfony2

**[image: texto en negrita]**

este es el codigo que tengo y por mas que lo he revisado no encuentro el error:

**tree.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
 {% block stylesheets %}
     {{ parent() }}
     <style type="text/css">
         ul{
             list-style: none;
         }
     </style>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-3" id="nested" style="color: #ddd ">
                 <div class="heading" style="color: #666">Categorias</div>
                 <ul>

                     {% for  masters in masters %}
                     <li style="margin: 0 ">
                         <a href="#" data-status="{{ masters.hasChildren() }}"
                            style="margin: 0" class="btn-folder">
                             <span class='{% if masters.hasChildren() == 1 %} fa fa-folder-open {% else %}fa fa-folder{% endif %} '></span>
                             {{ masters.name }}
                                 {%render(controller('RecursoBundle:tree:nested' , {'rows':child , 'parent_id': masters.id})) %}
                             </a>
                     </li>
                     {% endfor %}

                 </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>

 {% endblock %}

 {% block javascripts %}
      {{ parent() }}
     <script rel="javascripts" src="{{ asset('bundles/recurso/js/tree.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**treeController.php**

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 private $_element = array();

    public function estructuraAction(Request $request){
        $context = $request->get('context');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category')->findBy(array(
            'context' => $context
        ));
//        $query = $em->getRepository('ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle:Category')->findAll();
        $this->_element['masters'] = $this->_element['child'] = array();

        if(count($query) > 0)
        {
            foreach($query as $element){
                if($element->getParent() == null)
                {

                    array_push($this->_element['masters'] , $element);
                }
                else
                {
                    array_push($this->_element['child'] , $element);
                }
            }
        }
     $elementos = $this->_element;
     $child = $elementos['child'];
     $masters = $elementos['masters'];
       return $this->render('RecursoBundle::tree.html.twig',array('child'=>$child,'masters'=>$masters));
    }

    public  function nestedAction( $rows = array(), $parent_id = 0){
        $html = "";
        if(!empty($rows))
        {
            $html.="<ul>";
            foreach ($rows as $row )
            {
                if($row->getParent()->getId() == $parent_id)
                {
                    $html.="<li style='margin: 0px'>";
                    $html.="<a href='#' data-status='{$row->hasChildren()}' style='margin: 0' class='btn-folder'>";
                    if($row->hasChildren()== 1)
                    {
                        $html.="<span class='fa fa-folder-open'></span>".$row->getName()."</a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $html.="<span class=''></span>".$row->getName()."</a>";
                    }

                    $html.=self::nestedAction($rows, $row->getId());
                    $html.="</li> " ;
                }
            }
            $html.="</ul>";
        }
        return  new Response($html);
    }
```

**tree.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-folder").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).attr("data-status") === "1" )
        {
            $(this).attr("data-status" , "0");
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("fa-folder-open").addClass("fa-folder");

        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("data-status" , "1");
            $(this).find("span").removeClass("fa-folder").addClass("fa-folder-open");
        }
        $(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Es posible que nestedAction, al devolver directamente un objeto Response, lo esté generando. Podrías probar a hacer lo mismo pero retornando el resultado de $this->render() Además, es una buena práctica usar el motor twig para generar y retornar html.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código puedo ver una cosa, si `$row->getName()` no está incrustando ese texto entonces seguramente está siendo colocado por algún comportamiento JS. Has probado refrescar la pantalla con el devtools abierto y javascript desactivado?